# OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device linkk

Tags: python, operating-system, youtube-dl

I wanted to uninstall the youtube-dl from my manjaro linux , but I can't help me to do it please

OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/usr/bin/youtube-dl' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-7mydo2pi/youtube-dl'

this error occured

pip uninstall youtube-dl

uninstalled

but

OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/usr/bin/youtube-dl' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-7mydo2pi/youtube-dl'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.